# Sign JAR file with thawte certificate

Tags: java, applet, certificate, jar-signing, thawte

I´m trying to sign my JAR file with a Thawte certificate but I´ve runned into some problems and will try to explain what I´ve done.

**Step 1**

I´ve created a keystore file in jks format using the following command:

> keytool -genkey -keystore keystore -alias alias -keyalg RSA -keysize

And then generating a certificate:

> keytool -certreq -alias alias -keystore keystore -file file.csr

After I´ve done this I did send the generated certificate request to Thawte for confirmation.

**Step 2 - Notice: This is done on an other computer.**

After I while I´ve received a email from Thawte containing a confirmation and a Code Signing Certificate.

When I´ve received this confirmation I created two .cer files. One containing the received certificate and another containing a Thawte intermediate certificate that I got from their website. I imported these into my keystore that I used in step one.

**Step 3**

The last thing I dig was to signed my JAR file using the following command:

> jarsigner C:\signed\file.jar keystore

Everything went fine except I get this warning:

> Warning: The signer certificate will expire within six months. No -tsa
>   or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a
>   times tamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the
>   signer certificate's expiration date (2014-06-02) or after any future
>   revocation date.

And when I´m trying to deploy my JAR file the browser says that it´s a self-signed applet.

Does anyone know what I´m missing?

Kind regards / H

Comment: Look into using `gencert` with the [`-validity` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#Commands).

Comment: First of all you should try this command `jarsigner -verify -certs -verbose file.jar` to ensure that the jar file is signed with the correct certificate.